# Event bus Guava has an unbounded queue

Tags: java, events, garbage-collection, guava

I am scared to use event bus http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained as I think its using unbounded queue internally. If a lot of message are post to it. It might run into full gc.

Is there exists a similar implementation which does the same thing which is unbounded queue?

Comment: My question would have to be, why do you consider this a problem?

Comment: I wouldn't assume that would cause any problems until you can actually demonstrate the problem in reality.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, Guava uses an [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html), which is unbounded:

> An unbounded thread-safe queue based on linked nodes.

See [line 151-158 of EventBus.java](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.java#150).

> ```
> /** queues of events for the current thread to dispatch */
> private final ThreadLocal<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<EventWithHandler>>
>     eventsToDispatch =
>     new ThreadLocal<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<EventWithHandler>>() {
>   @Override protected ConcurrentLinkedQueue<EventWithHandler> initialValue() {
>     return new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<EventWithHandler>();
>   }
> };
> ```

You could always modify the code to use e.g. [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html). Have you looked into other solutions that are similar, e.g. [disruptor](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/)?

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with Arjit that an unbounded queue can be considered disadvantageous in certain scenarios. For example, if I have a service running that consumes messages from various sources to process them and I don't know the rate of incoming messages. It might exceed the processing speed of my worker/consumer and I might want to establish the following contract: Posting new messages to the workers will fail or block if there are still many messages pending. This will not only prevent running out of memory but also guarantee that messages will actually be processed within a certain time frame. Additionally clients will receive direct feedback if the service is running at its limits.

@Arjit: You can check out MBassador on https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador

It is very similar to Google Guava event bus but offers more features - bounded message queues being one of them. It is also very fast and its internal design allows a great deal of customization and extension. Up to know, I was able to address most of the feature requests from other users within short periods of time. Maybe you give it a try.